# Bulk collect sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

i made a data_object by myself :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_object AS OBJECT(
 number_type     NUMBER,
 varchar_type    VARCHAR2(20)
 )
```

and then i create type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_nt IS TABLE OF my_object;
```

And I want with nested table and this object make a procedure, that will be return number of employyes of some departments. I ve got Two tables: employees and department a this is my code:

```
DECLARE
  enum_dname  my_nt := my_nt();
PROCEDURE print_l IS
    BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('---------------------------------------------------------');
     FOR i IN 1..enum_dname.COUNT
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(enum_dname(i));
      END LOOP;
   END;
 BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(emp_id) as number_of, department_name
    BULK COLLECT INTO enum_dname
    FROM employees e, department d
    WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
    GROUP BY department_name;
   print_l;
  END;
```

And it show me errors : PLS - 00306: Wrong numbers of argument in call type: PUT_LINE

and PL\SQL : ORA - 00947:not enough values

THANK YOU!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `enum_dname(i).number_type` or `enum_dname(i).varchar_type` instead of just `enum_dname(i)`. Have you tried that ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal: I think you should make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors. As @SudiptaMondal pointed out ([and as here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1200142/266304)) you can't pass an object to `put_line()`, you have to pass a single string value - or something which evaluates to a string, which can be concatenated or implicit converted or whatever. So here you might do:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(enum_dname(i).varchar_type || ': ' || enum_dname(i).number_type);
```

or however you want to format that output. Using `dbms_output` for anything except debugging generally not a good idea as you have no control over whether someone using your code has output enabled. But this may be enough for this exercise.

The second problem, causing the ORA-00947, is because your query is trying to bulk collect two scalar variables into a collection of objects. You need to include the object constructor:

```
SELECT my_object(COUNT(emp_id), department_name)
BULK COLLECT INTO enum_dname
...
```